# Using dplyr: filter, mutate, case_when, and sum of absolute difference

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

A sample data looks like:

```
structure(list(role = c("r1", "c1", "r2", "c2"), v1 = c(1200, 
0, 1200, 0), v2 = c(900, 500, 900, 900), v3 = c(600, 800, 600, 
1800), v4 = c(300, 900, 300, 2700)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), codepage = 65001L)
```

What I'm trying to do is **sum** the **absolute difference** between v1, v2, v3, v4, and **certain numbers** (see below). The output I'm looking for is:

```
+------+------+-----+------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| role | v1   | v2  | v3   | v4   | accuracy                                                                |
+------+------+-----+------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| r1   | 1200 | 900 | 600  | 300  | 5400 = abs(v1 - 3600) + abs(v2 - 2700) + abs(v3 - 1800) + abs(v4 - 300) |
+------+------+-----+------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| c1   | 0    | 500 | 800  | 900  | 400 = abs(v1 - 0) + abs(v2 - 300) + abs(v3 - 600) + abs(v4 - 900)       |
+------+------+-----+------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| r2   | 1200 | 900 | 600  | 300  | 5400 = abs(v1 - 3600) + abs(v2 - 2700) + abs(v3 - 1800) + abs(v4 - 300) |
+------+------+-----+------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| c2   | 0    | 900 | 1800 | 2700 | 3600 = abs(v1 - 0) + abs(v2 - 300) + abs(v3 - 600) + abs(v4 - 900)      |
+------+------+-----+------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- So for role == r1 and r2, I'm subtracting 3600, 2700, 1800,
  and 300, respectively from v1-v4
- And for role == c1 and c2, I'm subtracting 0, 300, 600, 900, respectively.

I tried the following code, but I get all NA's:

```
data <- data %>% mutate(accuracy =
case_when((role == 'r1') ~ 
 abs(v1 - 3600) + abs(v2 - 2700) + abs(v3 - 1800) + abs(v4 - 300),
(role == 'r2') ~ 
abs(v1 - 3600) + abs(v2 - 2700) + abs(v3 - 1800) + abs(v4 - 300),
(role == 'c1') ~ 
abs(v1 - 0) + abs(v2 - 300) + abs(v3 - 600) + abs(v4 - 900),
(role == 'c2') ~
abs(v1 - 0) + abs(v2 - 300) + abs(v3 - 600) + abs(v4 - 900)))
```

**Update: The code above works fine. I think the problem is that in a bigger dataset, there are several NA's, which seems to be messing up the code. How can I deal with NA's when using case_when? For example, for missing values, when subtracting, I would like R to just disregard NAs (e.g., NA - 3600 = -3600)**

Comment: Missing comma at end of `role == 'c1'` case.

Comment: `accuracy = if_else(role %in% c("r1", "r2"), abs(v1 - 3600) + abs(v2 - 2700) + abs(v3 - 1800) + abs(v4 - 300), abs(v1 - 0) + abs(v2 - 300) + abs(v3 - 600) + abs(v4 - 900))` should work

Comment: I can't reproduce, once I fix the missing `,` and trailing `)`.

Comment: I fixed missing comma and parentheses; @Hugh, there are more roles (8 in total); can you please help considering a different way?

Comment: The fixed code does not give the correct answers for me (no NAs).

Comment: Use e.g. `coalesce(v1, 0)` to use a 0 whenever `v1` is missing.

Comment: @Axeman where would coalesce go in that line of code?

Answer (score 1):

Mutating the original data:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    across(v1:v4, \(v) coalesce(v, 0)),
    accuracy = case_when(
      role %in% c('r1', 'r2') ~ abs(v1 - 3600) + abs(v2 - 2700) + abs(v3 - 1800) + abs(v4 - 300),
      role %in% c('c1', 'c2') ~ abs(v1 - 0) + abs(v2 - 300) + abs(v3 - 600) + abs(v4 - 900)
    )
  )
```

Or keeping the data as-is:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    accuracy = case_when(
      role %in% c('r1', 'r2') ~ abs(coalesce(v1, 0) - 3600) + abs(coalesce(v2, 0) - 2700) + 
        abs(coalesce(v3, 0) - 1800) + abs(coalesce(v4, 0) - 300),
      role %in% c('c1', 'c2') ~ abs(coalesce(v1, 0) - 0) + abs(coalesce(v2, 0) - 300) + 
        abs(coalesce(v3, 0) - 600) + abs(coalesce(v4, 0) - 900)
    )
  )
```